# Moving/copying one remote database to another remote database

Tags: mysql, database, heroku, migrate

I'm using heroku to deploy my app. So far, I've been using a development version of my app, and seeding some data into it. I also have a production version set up on heroku.
Both apps are using a mysql database hosted with ClearDB to store the data.
I simply want to move the data from the development version to the production version.
Using MySql Workbench, I exported the dev data to a file and tried to import it to the prod db, but I got an access denied error because it tried to log into the dev db with production credentials.
The databases have identical table/row/column structure. How can I take the data from one and insert it into the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of the 'mysql' and 'mysqldump' command line
clients to "copy" one database's contents to the other. Here's an example of
how to do this:

```
mysqldump --single-transaction -u (old_database_username) -p -h (old_database_host) (database_name) | mysql -h (new_host) -u (new_user) -p -D (new_database)
```

with line breaks:

```
mysqldump --single-transaction -u (old_database_username) 
-p -h (old_database_host) (database_name) | mysql -h (new_host)
-u (new_user) -p -D (new_database)
```

Answer (score 1):

add Taps gem to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'taps'
```

you should be able to pull your development data to your local development environment with:

```
heroku db:pull --app your_development_app_name
```

then push it to production environment:

```
heroku db:push --app your_production_app_name
```

this will completely overwrite the db schema and data, so make sure you are careful with it.  hope it helps!

_ryan

Comment: I didn't try this, ended up using my own way instead. What does the taps gem do?

Comment: Taps provides the db:pull and db:push heroku commands.  The cool thing about it is you don't have to use a database-specific dump / copy command.

Comment: It's for syncing a deployed database with a local database and vice versa.  Very handy.  http://rubygems.org/gems/taps

Comment: Very cool. Wouldnt the commands that you gave pull and push the Heroku Postgres database, and not a cleardb/auxiliary database?

Comment: The default configuration uses the heroku db.  You can also point it to external db's by specifying the URLs on the command line.  See examples here:  http://rubydoc.info/gems/taps/0.3.24/frames

Comment: Yep, I assumed that something like that is possible. I'll accept your answer now, even though I didnt test it.