# Forking/Copying Heroku ClearDB to development environment

Tags: heroku, fork, cleardb

I'm setting up a development environment on heroku for my app and I'm having an issue copying over the DB. My current DB is ClearDB and I usually connect to it via Workbench. However, if I try to export the DB and iimport into my staging environment I get a credential issue.

I found this post on SO with regards to this issue:
[Moving/copying one remote database to another remote database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334938/moving-copying-one-remote-database-to-another-remote-database)

And the solution is here:

```
mysqldump --single-transaction -u (old_database_username) -p -h (old_database_host) (database_name) | mysql -h (new_host) -u (new_user) -p -D (new_database)
```

But even if I run this, I'm still running into an issue with credentials. The execution wants both passwords at the same time, for old DB and new DB so it keeps failing.

I tried to inline the -p but it still asks for password. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, that was a silly mistake. The reason I was having issues is that after option such as -u or -h, there is a space while in the option for password, there is no space. I.E.

```
mysqldump --single-transaction -u old_database_username -pPasswordOld -h old_database_host database_name | mysql -h new_host -u new_user -pPasswordNew -D new_database
```

Once corrected, everything worked as expected.